# How to trigger Azure Data Factory pipeline from Web application? Rest API call possible?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to do Rest API call from web app to data factory to trigger pipeline?
We have need to let end-users in web app to let trigger integration executed by data factory.

If not possible what are workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using logic app.

with logic apps that have a request trigger and the pipeline trigger a data factory workflow as below.

[image]